# Convert Little Endian to Big Endian - Not getting expected result

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a very small code where I am trying to convert a 16 bit number from little endian to big endian format.

The value of number is 0x8000 and after conversion I am expecting it to be as 0x0080 - but I am getting some different value as mentioned below:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
        int num = 0x8000;
        int swap = (num>>8) | (num<<8);
        std::cout << swap << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

The program outputs 8388736 as value which in hex is 0x800080 - I am not sure what wrong am I doing?

Comment: On almost all platforms, `int` is a **32** bit type. You initialize `num` to `0x00008000`, and all bits are significant.

Comment: Using just bit operations is valid for *unsigned int*. For signed type the bit representation is different.

Comment: Use `(unsigned) short int`, or better, `(u)int16_t`, then you will get the result you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do `0x8000 << 8` you'll get `0x800000`. If you `|` that with `0x80` you get the answer you now get. You need to filter away the upper part:

```
int swap = (num>>8) | (0xFF00 & (num<<8));
```

Suggestion: Use fixed width types, like `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` and `uint64_t`.

Comment: Thanks - so is this the general way always to swap 16 bits number?

Comment: No, general way is to use `htons()` and `ntohs()` functions

Comment: Thanks - I meant using bit pattern - in many places I see code like - (num << 8 ) | (num >> 8) ?

Comment: @Programmer That works with `uint16_t`. If you use a type wirh more than 16 bits, you need a bitwise AND to remove any set bits above the 16th bit